# CSS modules malformed using Webpack, Typescript and React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've been trying to learn React by doing a conversion of a webpage that I built with plain HTML and CSS. I'm currently playing with CSS modules but some of the CSS that's injected in to `<style>` tags seems to be a bit malformed: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoER0.png). Strangely enough it doesn't affect *all* of the CSS classes.

I went poking around as it looks like some of the CSS wasn't being applied, this component currently looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB6O9.png) but should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICIbg.png).

My React components are structured like this:

```
├── compA
    ├── index.tsx
    └── styles.css
├── compB
    ├── index.tsx
    └── style.css
```

and I'm importing the CSS files in to the TSX files with: `import "./style.css";`. What am I missing here?

webpack.config.js:

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
    
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        main: "./src/index.tsx",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
        plugins: [
            new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
                configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, "./tsconfig.json"),
                extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"]
            })
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: { modules: true }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the behavior of CSS modules, because the intention is for you to be importing your CSS modules as if they were JS:

```css
.foo {
  background: red;
}
```

```js
import styles from './foo.css'
export default () => <div className={styles.foo} />
```

Rather than using the classNames as strings. The name mangling is intentional to avoid conflicts, because there's no real scope in CSS. To preserve classnames, you can use `:global`:

```css
:global(.foo) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I've been playing with this for the better part of two days! I may have stumbled across the answer sooner and not even realised! You live, you learn.